# Prestashop 1.6, my class don't work in other modules

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-modules

I've creating a module with in the module a class extends to the ObjectModel :
module name :

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class StoreOrder extends ObjectModel
{
    public $id_store_order;
    public $id_customer;
    public $nature_piece;
    public $client_code;
    public $internal_reference;
    public $store_code;
    public $store_name;
    public $ticket_date;
    public $custumer_name;
    public $ticket_number;
    public $product_number;
    public $total_ht;
    public $total_ttc;
    public $payment_mode;

    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'ps_store_order',
        'primary' => 'id_store_order',
        'fields' => array(
            'id_store_order' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
            'id_customer' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
            'store_code' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'store_name' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'ticket_date' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'ticket_number' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'product_number' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'total_ht' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'total_ttc' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'payment_mode' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
        )
    );

    public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function getByIdCustomer($id_customer) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ps_store_order` WHERE `id_customer` = ".$id_customer;
        $result = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
        return $result;
    }


}
```

But if I include this class in other module to use it it's blocking at the step "_PS_VERSION_" is not defined, and il I remove the condition it's returning nothing (the code is stock I don't know why)

Thank's you..

Answer (score 0):

- You should not check the "_PS_VERSION_" on your object models
- You should not add "ps_" prefix to your table name on your object models:

`'table' => 'store_order',`

try this:

```
include_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'path-to-your-model';
dd(StoreOrder::getByIdCustomer(2));
```

It is also advisable to use a (int) for "$id_customer" :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ps_store_order` WHERE `id_customer` = " . (int)$id_customer;
```